# Need help to connect with MongoDB

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

I need a little help to connect my code with MongoDB. I have created a simple online shopping application with hibernate, Servlets and JSP. I am able to connect the code with MySQL and it works fine. But i tried changing the hibernate.config.xml file and added up mongoDB jars and tried connecting it with mongoDB its not happening. Can some one please help me out.

[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHy8j.png)

[Error in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpOs9.png)

Comment: have u got any error??? please share code

Comment: Hi Please find attached the image of the error in coonsole.

Comment: am not able to share the entire code here. Can i share it with u thru mail. please lemme know ur id

Comment: pankaj.saboo08@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to follow this book MongoDB for Java Developers by [PACKT Publishing](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/mongodb-java-developers) or you can go through the official course provided by [MongoDB University : M101J MongoDB for Java Developers](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101J/about).

Well, the book provides knowledge how to connect MongoDB with Java Applications such as JavaSE & JavaEE.